# Parsing css background url and selector using regex

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to change an HTML page that has inline styles, I want to make a regex expression that captures the background url and the selector, example:

```
<div>some html here</div>
<style>#some-selector {
  padding-top: 408px;
}
#some-selector .bg {
  background-image: url(www.some-url.com/some-image.jpg);
}
#some-selector {
  background-position: 43% 97%;
}
```

what I want to capture here is `#some-selector .bg` and `www.some-url.com/some-image.jpg`, keep in mind that the HTML page is big, and the expression should be fast

I came up with this expr `<style[\s\S]*?[>}\/\n](.*){[\s\S]*?background.*?url\((.*?)\)` but it's not working correctly, I know that I the first `[\s\S]` should be greedy but when i remove the `?` it leads to catastrophic backtracking `<style[\s\S]*[>}\/\n](.*){[\s\S]*?background.*?url\((.*?)\)` it does work on small strings but on the whole page it causes catastrophic backtracking, i've used regex101 to test it.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: here's an example https://regex101.com/r/ZMxOSz/1

Comment: Which tool or language you're using? It is not a good idea to parse a CSS with regex; therefore; you should use a CSS parser.

Comment: I am using PHP, I think extracting CSS and parsing it will take much more time than just using regex, and in this case, every ms matters

Comment: Nooo...parser is always the best choice since regexes may backfire if the css file is dynamic.Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/7571182) as to why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***update***
After a closer look, I offer 2 soulutions that mitigate backtracking issue's to a relative degree.
Before looking at them, I want to point out that there are only a very few delimiters associated with CSS syntax.
Moreover, it's more related to the order and content of allowed characters that define CSS syntax.

The cure to backtracking is to restrict the regex engine to fewer allowable
characters to match and withing strategic position.
If you look at the CSS specification here -> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html
you'll notice that it is entirely defined by regular expressions.
That indicates CSS parsers are entirely constructed with chopped version of regex.

However, while it would be an interesting exercise to put it into a
all encompasing regex, I will decline that challenge, because there is
nothing in it for me.

Instead, I offer these 2 regex tailored to your request.

Fisrt one:

- Matches only the first `url()` block within the `<style>` element

`<style[^>]*?>(?:[^{}:]*{[^{}]*?:[^{}()]*?})*?(?:([^{}:]*){[^{}]*?:\s*url\s*\(\s*([^{}()]*?)\s*\)\s*})`

see -> https://regex101.com/r/2SNIks/1

---

Second one:

- Matches all the `url()` blocks with the `<style>` element

`(?:<style[^>]*?>|(?!^)\G)(?:(?:(?!</style)[^{}:])*{[^{}]*?:[^{}()]*?})*?(?:([^{}:]*){[^{}]*?:\s*url\s*\(\s*([^{}()]*?)\s*\)\s*})`

see -> https://regex101.com/r/d8q6LH/1

---

For both regex,

- The selector is in group 1
- The url is in group 2

Comment: Thanks for your time, But the your regex expression does not work on a real world example, as I said the hml page is big, I added <style so the regex engine does not try to match html elemets which makes it faster, here's a link to real world example https://regex101.com/r/4tqovY/1 , also the selector is not always an id so doesnt always start with #

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. Added some alternatives that hopefully work better for you.

Comment: Thanks the second one is working, really wanna upvote your answer but don't have enough reputation, I also got downvoted for my question :')

Comment: I upvoted you. By 'second one' do you mean on this page ?

Comment: I mean the second expr in your answer

Comment: Oh, I upvoted your question, you should have enough reputation to both Accept this answer and upvote it as well. That is if it helped you out.

Comment: I accepted the question, but need 15 rep to upvote, only have 11 :(